# Messed Up Spacing After Button Click in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, spacing

I'm trying to create a GUI using Tkinter for a Pip-boy from Fallout 3. I'm running into a problem where after I click a button in one of the frames, the spacing between the buttons gets messed up. This spacing change happens for all but one of the buttons in the frame (the Lockpick one).

This is what I want the button spacing to look like (what it looks like before I click a button):[image]

This is what happens after I click a button (in this case the Barter one)
[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
from tkinter import *

# to read descriptions of each skill from a text file
with open("skills.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

# function that updates the label with a different description when the corresponding button is clicked
def show_skill_desc(index):
    desc['text'] = lines[index-1]


# makes the window and frame
root = Tk()
root.geometry("1024x600")
root.title("Skills")
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid()

# creates the label
Label(root, text="Stats").grid(row=0, column=0)

# list of skills which will each have their separate labels
skills_list = ["Barter", "Big Guns", "Energy Weapons", "Explosives", "Lockpick", "Medicine",
               "Melee Weapons", "Repair", "Science", "Small Guns", "Sneak", "Speech", "Unarmed"]

# placing the label in the frame
desc = Label(root, text="", padx=30, wraplength=600, justify=LEFT)
desc.grid(row=2, column=1)

# creates a button for each skill
button_list = []
for i in range(12):
    button_list.append(Button(root, text=skills_list[i], width=40,
                              height=2, command=lambda c=i: show_skill_desc(button_list[c].grid_info()['row']), padx=0, pady=0))
    button_list[i].grid(row=i+1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

The purpose of the GUI is to display the description of each skill, when the button for a skill is clicked.

Does anyone know why the spacing change happens? Thank you!

Comment: Seems like the height of the Label is greater than the height of your button because of the multiline text. You could also play around with the `padx` property of your Label `desc`

Comment: Changing the height or padx of the Label doesn't help, I have the problem still.

Comment: As said in other comment, the height of the label is larger than that of the button in row 2.  Try adding `rowspan=10` (or other value > 1) and `sticky='nw'` to `desc.grid(...)` .

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong with spacing. It worked for me.:)